# Visual Studio 2015 no documentation tooltip

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

Weirdly enough, the tooltip documentation on my Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition when using Xamarin 6.1.1 (and I think the previous version as well) doesn't appear correctly. They all written as "To be added", even on the common C# method like `int.TryParse()`.

If I'm working different project other than Xamarin (such as a console app project), there's even no "To be added" tooltip. Just blank.

I reckon there's such tooltip help, that for example, explaining briefly of the method usage. I don't know why it's gone, maybe accidentally pressed something.

Is there any way to show it / maybe I need to download it first?

[image]

Comment: This is what they actually have in Xamarin. `To be added` is quite common. VS simply displays it.

Comment: The tooltip in this case is `To be added`, so nothing wrong here. and as @GSerg says, thats common in Xamarin

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin's documentation is horrible, it's full of  `"To be added"` comments, so that's not a problem with your computer.

The tooltip not showing up, however, can be a problem with your Visual Studio. If restarting the computer does not solve that, you'd have to clear up Visual Studio's cache

Comment: tooltip, for example, only shown the method structure tooltip. I believe there was also a brief explanation under that.

Comment: I meant in my current state.